# Recreate image from packets captured by wireshark

Tags: image, security, wireshark, packet-sniffers, hexdump

I have done some socket programming for sending and receiving the hex data of an image to server side. Now I am using wireshark for capturing this data.  I have also used npcap loopback adapter for capturing localhost traffic. Is there any way to convert this hex data to corresponding image?

**EDIT**

I have opened a .jpg image in binary mode, then this binary is converted to hex using hex = binascii.hexlify(binary). This hex data is sending to server.

On the receiving side, hex is read and converted back to binary to write to image file(.jpg)

when I used wireshark I got this output:

[image]

Comment: Without any more details it'll be hard? What file format dow you have? How's the hex data made up? An initial search gives https://onlinehextools.com/convert-hex-to-image

Comment: Thank you for that! But how can we copy the hex data which is divided into different packets?

Comment: Are you probably looking for the Wireshark developers guide  https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ ?

Comment: ok I will check that..